# How I can customize a button using java swing?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-7

How I can customize a button and to have it on a display panel in the same way as in a tool bar.
[image]

What I really want is to add a button to a panel, and that look like to tool bar button.
I tried copying the button on the toolbar and pasting it into the center of the panel and shows what happened the previous image.

Comment: can you add a little more info in what you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use properties Like, border, margin and fillXXX to make it like that on toolBar.

Answer (score 0):

There are other Swing objects for toolbars which you may find more suitable than trying to add a button.  See here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html